# React-redux: Nested array is being duplicated

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux, nested

I'm trying to create an order table (array) that has a nested "products" array in each order.

The order table is rendering as expected, but the products are the same for every order.

**OrderTable Component** (simplified for clarity)

```
class OrderTable extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchPtOrders(this.props.patient_id);
      }

    renderOrders(orders) {
        return orders.map((order) => {
          return (
            <tr key={order.id}>
              <td>
                <ProductTable id={order.id}/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          );
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { orders, loading, error } = this.props.orderTable;

        return (
          <div class="container divcon">
            <h1>Orders</h1>
            <table class="pto">
              <tbody>
                {this.renderOrders(orders)}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default OrderTable;
```

`<ProductTable id={orders.id}/>` arrays the products and is basically a copy of the above (minus the ProductTable component).

I tried debugging using IDs (3000022 and 3000023) and found that everything is being done in [batches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcY63.jpg).

3000022 contains products / 3000023 is empty.

The response from the requests is being used for both IDs, and is overwritten with every iteration. Only the last response is used for every order.

**ProductTable Container:**

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    ProductTable: state.order_products.ProductTable,
    order_id: ownProps.id
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    fetchPtOrderProducts: (id) => {
      dispatch(fetchPtOrderProducts(id)).then((response) => {
        !response.error ? dispatch(fetchOrderProductsSuccess(response.payload.data)) : dispatch(fetchOrderProductsFailure(response.payload.data));
      });
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProductTable);
```

**Product Fetch action:**

```
export function fetchPtOrderProducts(id) {
  const request = axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: `${ROOT_URL}/order_product/search.php?s=${id}`,
    headers: []
  });

  return {
    type: FETCH_PTORDER_PRODUCTS,
    payload: request
  };
}
```

**Product Success action:**

```
export function fetchOrderProductsSuccess(order_products) {
  console.log("products fetched")
  return {
    type: FETCH_ORDER_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
    payload: order_products
  };
}
```

**Product Reducers**

```
case FETCH_ORDER_PRODUCTS:// start fetching products and set loading = true
    return { ...state, ProductTable: {order_products:[], error: null, loading: true} };

case FETCH_ORDER_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS:// return list of products and make loading = false
    return { ...state, ProductTable: {order_products: action.payload, error:null, loading: false} };
```

How can I make `orders.map()` and `<ProductTable />` array [one ID at a time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dQQ9.jpg)?

Thanks for you help! Sorry if anything is unclear... I'm a complete newbie.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding your question, but I do see you creating two different variables both named "orders" here.   Perhaps you should change the line to "return orders.map( (order) => {" and use "order" inside the return clause.

Comment: shouldn't it be `orders.map((order) => ` and then use it like this `<ProductTable id={order.id}/>`? not the singular `order` variable instead of the duplicate plural variable `orders`.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I tried changing to `orders.map((order) =>` as well as the using `order` for everything inside of the return clause, but the result is the same.

Comment: I think we're missing some important details here. You've posted some React component code but your question seems to be about the loading of data in Redux actions. I'm guessing we need to see your reducer/actions.

Comment: Either that or the call to `renderOrders` or the implementation of `ProductTable` has issues. It's not clear what you're asking right now, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Jacob. I added in as much detail as possible without flooding the post with code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you are overriding the same field in your state.
You should change `ProductTable` field to maintain `order_id` for each product list. It should be a map of `order_id` to `order_products`.

Note that my code might contain mistakes because I have no runnable example to edit.
Something like this:

**ProductTable Container:**

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    orderProductTable: state.order_products.ProductTable[ownProps.id],
    order_id: ownProps.id
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    fetchPtOrderProducts: (id) => {
      // Add `id` argument to fetchOrderProductsSuccess here
      dispatch(fetchPtOrderProducts(id)).then((response) => {
        !response.error ? dispatch(fetchOrderProductsSuccess(id, response.payload.data)) : dispatch(fetchOrderProductsFailure(response.payload.data));
      });
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(OrderProductTable);
```

Product Fetch action:

```
export function fetchPtOrderProducts(id) {
  const request = axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: `${ROOT_URL}/order_product/search.php?s=${id}`,
    headers: []
  });

  return {
    type: FETCH_PTORDER_PRODUCTS,
    payload: {id}
  };
}
```

**Product Success action:**

```
export function fetchOrderProductsSuccess(id, order_products) {
  console.log("products fetched")
  // Add `id` field here
  return {
    type: FETCH_ORDER_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
    payload: {id, products: order_products}
  };
}
```

**Product Reducers**

```
case FETCH_ORDER_PRODUCTS:// start fetching products and set loading = true
    return { ...state, ProductTable: {...(state.ProductTable || {}), [action.payload.id]: {order_products:[], error: null, loading: true}}};

case FETCH_ORDER_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS:// return list of products and make loading = false
    return { ...state, ProductTable: {...(state.ProductTable || {}), [action.payload.id]: {order_products: action.payload.products, error:null, loading: false}}}};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bsalex! I made the changes you advised, and now I'm getting a `TypeError: dispatch(...).then is not a function` error when running `dispatch(fetchPtOrderProducts(id)).then((response)...` in the container file.

Comment: This started happening when I changed `payload: {id}` in the Product Fetch Action. I think it has something to do with how the reducer is returning, but I am hitting a wall again.